# setClickable() to false wont work on Android ChromeCast's MediaRouterButton

Tags: android, android-view, chromecast, android-touch-event

I have a MediaRouterButton for chromecast in my android device.
Now i want to programmatically enable/disable its click,  so I have such line of code:

```
mediaButton.setClickable( false ).
```

But it doesnt disable its click , the chromecast dialog still show up.

I try checking the source code for it, it overrides the performClick() method, but after I set a break point to this method and debug, i find no methods in the stack other than this performClick().

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: use setEnabled() instead of setClickable()

Comment: it doesnt work... mediaroutebutton is actually extending from view directly instead of a butoon

Comment: What you are trying to do is against the intended design for the Cast button, what is your use case?

Comment: when I swipe up my main Imageview i want to set the alpha value to all my buttons in toolbar fading away as well as disable them,

Comment: and I wanna know why it is happening? the button is just extending from a view class, why i cant set it to unclickable? thank you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have a work around....

Just override the MediaRouteButton, override its performClick() method, insert the logic you wanna do.

```
public class CustomizedChromesCastButton extends MediaRouteButton {
    private boolean enable = true;
    public CustomizedChromesCastButton( Context context ){
        super( context );
    }
    public CustomizedChromesCastButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super( context, attrs );
    }
    public CustomizedChromesCastButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
        super( context, attrs, defStyleAttr );
    }

    public void setCastEnable( boolean enable ){
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public boolean performClick(){
        if( enable ){
            return super.performClick();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```